# The Puiseux series and gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

Just a thought: In the Taylor expansion of an analytic function $f(x)$, the $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ appears in the coefficient for $x^n$. So if we use a Puiseux series instead, would we get a $\Gamma(n/k)$ appearing in the coefficient for $x^{n/k}$?

I searched around and the only related result is that the Gamma function values appear in the general [Newton binomial expansion theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html).

Comment: What's your question exactly?  Isn't the Puisuex series expansion of an analytic function equal to its Taylor expansion? (i.e. the coefficients of fractional powers are all 0)

Comment: To make $1/\Gamma(n+1-a)$ appear look at the fractional derivative of $x^n 1_{x > 0}$

Comment: I meant that whether the Gamma function would appear in the general case of nonanalytic functions, with Puiseux series not being a Taylor series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a function $f(z)$ with a converging Puiseux series in powers of $z^{1/k}$, say

$$ f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^{j/k}$$
then
$$ f(z^k) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j$$
is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$, with
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left. \dfrac{d^n}{dz^n} f(z^k) \right|_{z=0} $$

No, there's no reason for this to involve $\Gamma(n/k)$.